# Show more details in event fullcalendar 4

Tags: php, fullcalendar-4

I can't figure out how to show more details in fullcalendar 4 event. Following this post:

> [[fullcalendar]Have listMonth display more details than month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48051252/fullcalendarhave-listmonth-display-more-details-than-month/48056490#48056490)

I tried this code without success:

```
eventRender: function( info ) {
  if (info.view.type == "timeGridWeek")
  {
     info.el.find('.fc-title').html('something');
  }
},
```

but i'm getting error : failure to parsing JSON. Do you have any idea, what i'm doing wrong? Thank you.

edit:
I figured out that get div with class name fc-title i can get with this code:

```
eventRender: function(info) {
  console.log(info.el.getElementsByClassName("fc-title"));
},
```

but can't find out how to append div or span or whatever element there.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i figured it out:

```
eventRender: function(info) {
  var user = document.createElement('div');
  user.innerHTML = info.event.extendedProps.calendarUser;
  info.el.lastChild.lastChild.appendChild(user);
}
```

this will add div to element with className '.fc-title'.

Comment: I have spent a lot of time serching this. Thank U.